# Not Able to get full text(Till End of Page) of Div using selenium javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
        List <WebElement> divList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#graphiql-container > div.editorWrap > div.editorBar > div.resultWrap > div > div > div.CodeMirror-scroll"));
        List<WebElement> elements= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(
                "#graphiql-container > div.editorWrap > div.editorBar > div.resultWrap > div > div > div.CodeMirror-scroll"))
                .findElements(By.xpath(".//*"));
        for (WebElement webElement : elements) {
            System.out.println(webElement.getText());
        }
```

I am using above code to get the entire text of particular div, however the string here return only visible text,however there is still more data till the end of page , it does not return it. Is there any way we can achieve it ?.
Putting in a nutshell i want to get full text of specific section of webpage till the end.

Comment: show us HTML code please

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: <div class="result-window"><div class="CodeMirror cm-s-graphiql CodeMirror-wrap"><div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 3px; height: 0px; top: 35px; left: 67px;"><textarea autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" style="position: absolute; padding: 0px; width: 1000px; height: 1em; outline: none;" tabindex="0"></textarea></div>